# PHP cronjob variables

Tags: php, variables, cron, constants

I have to complete an old project which uses a php cronjob. Within the cronjob I have to check a variable like this

```
defined('_CRONJOB') or die;
```

This constant can take different values to indicate the job to do:

```
switch(_CRONJOB){ 
//...more code
}
```

How can I set this variable when calling the cronjob. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you'll use cron to launch your script, you can use CLI parameters and pass some value into your script. To handle your parameters you can use just simple way, like:

```
define('_CRONJOB', $_SERVER['argv'][1]); //equal to 1-st parameter
```

In this case launch will be like:

```
/path/to/bin/php /path/to/script.php foo
```

And your `_CRONJOB` will be equal to `foo`

Alternative and more advanced way is to use [getopt()](https://www.php.net/getopt) and grab named parameter. That will be more readable and you'll be able not to rely on parameter order (i.e. that it will be first exactly). I recommend you to use this way.

Comment: ahh yes, it's a space. this is right, i knew the $_GET syntax seemed wrong

Comment: Well, you can't "pass" something like HTTP-GET uri in CLI mode because such call will be treated as file name

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your cronjobs are run, the most likely answer is `$argv`, or `$_SERVER['argv']`.

your script will point to `/path/to/cron/script/index.php var1 var2 var3`

again this issue can be very dependent on your server setup, but give this a shot

EDIT:
updated to correct variable syntax